# Is it possible to use <input> tags inside a php function which is then inside <form> tags?

Tags: php, html, forms, input

I am very new to both php and HTML and have been trying to wrap my head around them for the past few days. I am trying to create a questionnaire with radio buttons that is 56 questions long.

This is the generic layout I have right now

```html
<form action="index.php" name="My Form" method="POST">
      <ol>
        <li>
          <p>Do you eat cheese?</p><br />
          <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="0"/>Never<br />
          <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="1"/>In the past<br />
          <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="2"/>Sometimes<br />
          <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="4"/>Often<br /><br />
        </li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit the questionnaire"></input>
      </ol>
  </form>
```

Now, I need the 4 buttons on each question but I would prefer not to have to write it out 56 times with only the name changing (the plan is to change the name to "Q1", "Q2" etc). So, I was wondering if there is a way to create a function that saves me having to repeat it so often.

I tried variants of this

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php

        function inputs($counter)
            $questions = array("Q1","Q2");

            echo '
            <input type="radio" name=.$questions[$counter]; value="0" 
            />Never
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name=.$questions[$counter]; value="1" />In 
            the past
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name=.$questions[$counter]; value="2" 
            />Sometimes
            <br /> 
            <input type="radio" name=.$questions[$counter]; value="4" 
            />Often
            <br />
            <br /> ';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

With the intention of then going like this in the list item

```
<p>Do you eat cheese?<p><br />
<?php inputs(0);?>
```

(with the file containing the function already included)

And did at one point manage to get it to print out to the page (all correct but didn't transfer over into the index.php for calculations). I have a suspicion I should make inputs(0) equal to something, but I don't know.

So my questions are ->

1. Is it possible to put input into php functions like this and get them to output a value for the form (which can be later used for index.php)
2. If not, is there a way to create a subform form function, where each question is its own form and outputs a value into the larger form?
3. Should I just bite the bullet and write the questions?

Cheers

Comment: you have some misquoting/escaping within the function - as you are using single quotes for the string attribute values within the string should be quoted (generally speaking) with double quotes and the PHP variable needs to be escaped with a single quote then period (ie: `' . $var . '` )

Comment: Hi just so I understand, all you want to change each time is the `name`, from being 'Q1' to 'Q2'?

Comment: Are the values assign to the radio buttons critical - ie: `0,1,2,4`?

Comment: @TheCodesee yes, that's the only part I would like to change

Comment: @RamRaider They are used in the index.php script to figure out a score based on answers to the questions. I also know there are a few issues with the function code I posted, so thank you, I'l try and fix it with that in a bit

Comment: it's fine - but if you look at the second piece of code I posted it should assign those values as the value to the individual radio button - the name of which is changed `q1,q2,q3...` depeinding upon integer `i` passed to the function when called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function do what you need .

```
<?php
 function inputs($counter){
         $labels = ['Never','In the past','Sometimes','Often'];
         $questions = array("Q1","Q2");

    for($n=0; $n < $counter; $n++){

    echo '<input type="radio" name="'. $questions[0] .'" value="'. $n .'" />  '. $labels[$n] .' <br /> ';
    }
  }
?>

<!--  html -->

<p> Do you eat cheese? <p> <br />
<?php echo inputs(5); ?>

//where 5 is the number of inputs you need
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but this would not specifically work for me as I need to always have all the labels. What I've added to this is an array called $values (where $values = array(0,1,2,4);)  and done value=" '. $values[$n].' ";

Comment: yoy can put any labels you want inside this array $labels and it will be created automaticlly.

Comment: Sweet, thank you! [Also, for any other readers, this code does work in producing a value that can be read in a form. I will test others as well]

Comment: From the ones I have gotten, this answer is the one I went with. Simple enough for me and works like a treat. Thank you very much! [This comment was for any other readers reading this at a later date]

Comment: @samehanwar you should replace `0` with `$n` in `$questions` at `type="radio" name="'. $questions[0] .'"`

Comment: @Ivan86 no it shouldn't . check it again

Comment: You are right but now we come to the second problem.. All of his `radio` buttons will have the same name `Q1` because `$questions[0]` will **always** be executed as `[0]`. It's needed for the radio buttons of the same group but he mentioned 56 groups, all the others will also have `Q1`. Am I right?

Comment: You are right @Ivan86 - it should be `$questions[$counter]` - but the other problem is the value assigned - it will be from `0,1,2,3` rather than `0,1,2,4`

Comment: That too, you are right. I didn't spot that one. This `$counter` variable makes no sense at all in this context as he has a fixed set of `checkbox labels` that is set to `4 members` so why would you ever write `<?php echo inputs(5); ?>`. Too many problems with this code for it to be accepted as the right answer. Maybe author should consider `edit` to make it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

    // Make sure you have 56 elements in the array
    $questions = array("Do you always eat cheese?", "Are you human?",
                       "Do you have a dog?", "Mr. Murphy is funny?",
                       ...);

    for($i=1; $i < 57; $i++)
    {
        echo '<table>
              <tr>
                  <td><p>'.$questions[$i-1].'</p></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="0"/>Never</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="1"/>In the past</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="2"/>Sometimes</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="4"/>Often</td>
              </tr>
              </table>';
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks for responding to me. As far as I can tell, your code works for what I need it to do, but I also can see you are trying to use a table. It may be the way I've coded it, but the radio circles do not come up in any table of any sort, but I don;t really mind because it works. Thanks again!

Comment: The table was meant to replace the `<br/>` tags you were listing. Also this way you can put `CSS` styles on the `table`, `rows` or `cells` and you have separate containers for each `radio`. And just to mention, the `table` borders/lines are invisible by default.

Comment: This prints 56 tables.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write this as an answer instead of a comment, because it will be too much code in it.

What you should do (at this state of learning):

Let the function *return* something to be echoed later. Second let's correct a small misstake:

```
<?php

function inputs($question) { // you were missing these { here

                           // missing ' here          and here + the dot  
    $html = '<input type="radio" name='.$question.' value="0"/>Never';
    // add some more html                 // better with " around the string
    $html += '<br/><input type="radio" name="'.$question.'" value="1" />In the past';
    // add whatever you like to add to that...

    // at the end let's return all we've got to use it later:
    return $html;
}


// and now you can do:
$questions = array("Q1","Q2");
for($i=0;$i<count($questions);$i++) {
     echo inputs($questions[$i]); // send only one question to the function
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank you for pointing out some syntax errors, I now realise those are kind of important. As for the code, I understand the function part, but I don't understand the second part. If I enter <?php inputs(1);?> underneath my question, the radio circles do not show up and I have 2 zeros at the top of my WAMPServer page I use to test it.

Comment: it's the `echo inputs(whatever)` that's important. Now we are returning the html to be echoed lated, which is much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I just bite the bullet and write the questions?

*Definitely not! That's way too much code!*

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want the `name` to change for each of the 56 different questions. While you were on the right track with an array, I think it would be easier to increment `$i` each time, like this:

```
function inputs($counter) {
   $i = 0
   while($i < 57) {
      echo'
      <input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="0" 
      />Never
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="1" />In 
      the past
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="2" 
      />Sometimes
      <br /> 
      <input type="radio" name="Q'.$i.'" value="4" 
      />Often
      <br />
      <br /> 
      ';
      $i++
   }
}
```

Comment: This kind of works, the problem would be I currently want to put the INPUTS function underneath each question, so I would end up with 56 input areas underneath. I can see what you're doing though, and it is useful, so thank you! What I think I would change --> Just get rid of the while loop and $i, and make counter equal to the question number

Comment: Once I do that, I can confirm it does work for what I want it to do, thanks! I knew it would be too much code to repeat but couldn't for the life of me figure out another way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this perhaps:

```
function inputs( $i ){
    $answers=array(
        'Never','In the past','Sometimes','Often'
    );
    foreach( $answers as $key => $answer ) echo "<div><input type='radio' name='Q{$i}' value='{$key}' />{$answer}</div>";
}

<p>Do you eat cheese?<p>
<?php inputs(0);?>

<p>Do you eat bananas?<p>
<?php inputs(1);?>
```

Assuming the values assign to each radio button are important ( `0,1,2,4` ) then rather than using the default numerical index (`$key`) as before then

```
function inputs( $i ){
    $answers=array(
        0   =>  'Never',
        1   =>  'In the past',
        2   =>  'Sometimes',
        4   =>  'Often'
    );
    foreach( $answers as $key => $answer ) echo "<div><input type='radio' name='Q{$i}' value='{$key}' />{$answer}</div>";
}
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you! The second part of the code works perfectly for what I want to do!